# ListView CollectionView results are mismatched

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm pasting only relevant code, the original code is too long.

I have a `listView1` that loads items from a property called `StudentsList`. This property has-

```
StudentName (String)  |     StudentAge (Int)
Alex                  -     13
Peter                 -     18
Donald                -     13
William               -     13
Ronald                -     15
```

Besides, I have a textbox `txtSearchByAge`. When I type an age (for example: `13`), I want the `listView1` to only display student(s) matching that age.

```
StudentName (String)  |     StudentAge (Int)
Alex                  -     13
Donald                -     13
William               -     13
```

The code behind:

```
    public MainWindow(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)    
    {    

    .................
    .................
    CollectionView view= (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView1.ItemsSource);    
    view.Filter = DoFilteringWork;
    .................
    .................       

    }

    private bool DoFilteringWork(object item)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchByAge.Text)) { return true; }

            return ((item as StudentsList).StudentAge.ToString().IndexOf(txtSearchByAge.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    }

    private void txtSearchByAge_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {       CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView1.ItemsSource).Refresh();
    }
```

This doesn't work. The results are mismatched, `listView1` does not show students with age=13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private ICollectionView view;
public MainWindow(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)    
{    

.................
.................
/* CollectionView */ view= (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView1.ItemsSource);    
view.Filter = DoFilteringWork;
.................
.................       

}

private bool DoFilteringWork(object item)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(txtSearchByAge.Text, out int age)) { return true; }

        return ((Student)item).StudentAge == age;
}

private void txtSearchByAge_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   view.Refresh();
}
```

The code is written assuming that the collection contains elements of the "Student" type

More complete version with comments:

```
    // Original collection with complete list.
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Student> students
        = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

    // Representation of the original collection with the ability to filter, sort, group.
    private ICollectionView view;

    // The field for storing the desired value.
    private int? searchAge;

    public MainWindow(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {

        //.................
        //.................

        // Create a view of the original collection.
        view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(students);
        view.Filter = DoFilteringWork;

        // Passing a view of the collection to the Window element for display.
        listView1.ItemsSource = view;
        //.................
        //.................       

    }

    private bool DoFilteringWork(object item)
    {
        // If the required age is not present, then show all the elements.
        if (searchAge == null)
            return true;

        // Otherwise, show only with an age equal to the desired one.
        Student student = (Student)item;
        return student.StudentAge == searchAge.Value;
    }

    private void txtSearchByAge_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Getting the required age value.
        int? sAge = null;
        if (int.TryParse(txtSearchByAge.Text, out int age))
            sAge = age;

        // Checking whether the desired age has changed or not.
        if (searchAge == sAge)
            return;

        // If the age has changed, then remember the new value.
        searchAge = sAge;

        // Call Refresh the collection view if it is not null.
        view?.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: I do not see in your code how you pass "view" to the View (ItemsControl or ListBox).
Therefore, I did not do this in my code either.